# Js Classes pass this (class) to jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using js classes to assign jQuery UI datepicker to dom elements. This all works but the issue I am having is with the `onSelect` parameter. `this` is set to the dom element, so I am unable to call a function within the class using `this`.

```
class form_validate{

        constructor(){
                 this.addDatePickers();
        }

    addDatePickers(){

       $(document).ready(function(){
                         console.log('called');
              var datepickers = document.getElementsByClassName('dh-datepicker');
            var contextClass= this;

            [].forEach.call(datepickers, function(d){   
              $(d).datepicker({ 
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                onSelect: function(contextClass){
                  console.log(this);
                  contextClass.calledf();
                }
              });
            }, contextClass);   
       })

    }

    calledf(){
            console.log('yeaa');
    }


}//end class

var validater= new form_validate();
```

I have also tried passing in the object `validator` and saving `this` to an variable and passing in (see `contextClass` above). How can I call an function within the class when `this` has changed?

https://jsfiddle.net/1t0wfuzw/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move up the line

```
var contextClass = this;
```

like this:

```
class form_validate {

  constructor() {
    this.addDatePickers();
  }

  addDatePickers() {
    var contextClass = this;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log('called');
      var datepickers = document.getElementsByClassName('dh-datepicker');

      [].forEach.call(datepickers, function(d) {
        $(d).datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          onSelect: function() {
            console.log(this);
            contextClass.calledf();
          }
        });
      }, contextClass);
    })
  }

  calledf() {
    console.log('yeaa');
  }

} //end class

var validater = new form_validate();
```

Comment: brilliant, I was focusing on the wrong issue. Thanks mate